# How to call COM methods from different threads

Tags: windows, winapi, com

I am trying to integrate a Windows COM API to my application using TLB file. My application is multi  threaded. All the READ calls can be in a single thread, ie the main thread. But all WRITE calls will be individual threads.

I am calling CoInitialize  (multithreaded) from the main thread. Subsequent READ calls from the same main thread are working. But READ or WRITE calls from other methods are throwing some error that the COM server connection is closed.

Tried calling CoInitialize from the other threads,but no change.

I need the ability call COM methods from different threads. How to do that?

Comment: [What is COM marshaling and how do I use it?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20151020-00/?p=91321)

Comment: AFAIK any thread that uses COM should call `CoInitialize` (or `CoInitializeEx`) beforehand. Not sure about other issues you have.

Comment: Difficult to say more w/o some reproducing bits of code https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Is the COM server in proc or out of proc. If in proc what threading model does it support.

Comment: If the COM object implements an Apartment-threaded model, you will have to *marshal* the COM object across thread boundaries, via either `CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream()` or `IGlobalInterfaceTable`. An Apartment-threaded object is not designed to be used across threads, so it will have to be proxied so the actual access remains in the thread that creates the object.

Comment: To expand: in COM, all objects have thread affinity unless you are explicitly told otherwise in the COM documentation (a handful of platform-provided objects) or unless the object is explicitly implemented and declared to be Free-threaded. The only thread that is allowed to make calls on the object (read or write, is irrelevant) is the thread that created it. All other threads must use a marshalled proxy object as described in other comments.

Answer (score -1):

According to the recommendations of the community, I sugest you could try to refer to the Blog:[According to the recommendations of the community](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20151020-00/?p=91321).

You could try to use COM marshaling to call COM methods from different threads.